Movie about virtual reality obsession?
I vaguely remember coming across a foreign film, (which I think was in French but I am not entirely sure), that focused on a depressed teenage boy whom did not feel at home with his wealthy family and in school.
Plot:

He encounters an online virtual reality game in which he makes a
close relationship with a few other online members, one of which is a
girl who stands as the leader of the group, and who he falls for. 
He becomes increasingly obsessed with the game to the point where he 
does nothing else. I can't recall why but the group has a falling out
with one another, and I think a suicide pact is made by the main boy 
and the girl, which he follows through by taking drugs at a
nightclub(?).
The final scene is of the main character acting funny and
entertaining a couple that he comes across in the bathroom, in which 
one of them begins to film him as he begins to overdose(?) and dies
in front of them.

I cannot find this movie anywhere and it's driving me crazy! Any help would be appreciated. 

When did you watch it?
